# Creación de un Spinner personalizado en Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

He seguido varios tutoriales para la creación de un Spinner personalizado en Android. Lamentablemente no termino de entender cómo funciona lo qué estoy haciendo, así que agradecería mucho que me echaran un cable para terminar de comprenderlo.

A continuación, dejo el código que he hecho siguiendo el tutorial.

```kotlin
package es.manuel.spinnerexample.ui.customSpinner

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import es.manuel.spinnerexample.R
import es.manuel.spinnerexample.databinding.ActivityCustomSpinnerBinding

class CustomSpinnerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding: ActivityCustomSpinnerBinding by lazy {
        ActivityCustomSpinnerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    private val viewModel: CustomSpinnerViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupViews()
    }

    private fun setupViews() {
        binding.spnCustomSpinnerPlanets.adapter =
            PlanetSpinnerAdapter(this, viewModel.planets)
    }


    companion object {
        fun newIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            return Intent(context, CustomSpinnerActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
package es.manuel.spinnerexample.ui.customSpinner

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import es.manuel.spinnerexample.data.entity.Planet
import es.manuel.spinnerexample.databinding.SpinnerSelectedItemBinding


class PlanetSpinnerAdapter(
    ctxt: Context,
    private val planets: List<Planet>
) :
    ArrayAdapter<Planet>(ctxt, 0, planets) {

    // TODO HACER
    private val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctxt)

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent)
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent)
    }

   private fun initView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
       val rowView = SpinnerSelectedItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
       val planet = planets[position]
       rowView.txtSpinnerSelectedItemKm.text = planet.order.toString()
       rowView.txtSpinnerSelectedItemName.text = planet.name
       return rowView.root
   }
}
```

```kotlin
package es.manuel.spinnerexample.ui.customSpinner

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import es.manuel.spinnerexample.data.base.Database

class CustomSpinnerViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val planets = Database.queryAllPlanets()
}
```

Entiendo que la idea principal es crear una clase que extienda de ArrayAdapter (el cual ya tiene lo necesario para crear un adaptador para el Spinner, ¿no?), lo que no termino de entender es qué hacen los métodos sobreescritos ni por qué tienen el mismo código. A mi forma de verlo, creo que uno es para cuando se muestra solo un item y el otro para cuando se muestra la lista de items, ¿cómo es posible que funcione teniendo el mismo código?

Comment: He conseguido llegar a una solución que parece funcionar. De todos modos, dejaré la pregunta abierta un tiempo más por si alguien ofrece una mejor solución. El repositorio quizás se vuelva privado, pero me aseguraré de dejar aquí la solución a la que llegué, por si alguna vez alguien necesita hacer lo mismo.

Comment: muestra un poco el codigo de tu adaptador, creo que te puedo ayudar, pero no respodere hasta que tenga una respuesta en concreta

Comment: Tienes todo el código en el enlace github, como comento en el mensaje. Si quieres edito la pregunta y lo añado. Gracias!

Comment: @CristhianJavierUlloaCarmona, como has pedido he añadido el código a la pregunta ^^. Espero que me puedas ayudar a mejorarlo. Gracias.

Comment: excelente, deme unos minutos y te respondo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te traigo uno código hecho 100% hecho por mi, te voy a explicar cada pazo de como lo cree, originalmente lo cree para usarlo en un listView personalizado, pero también sirve en tu caso.

La verdad no entendí al 100% tu código escrito en kotlin.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_list_view" />

<!-- <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_list_view"/>
    -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner list = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_list_view);

        final String[] headers = {
                "tips/importacia/header.json",
                "tips/porque/header.json",
                "tips/quehacer/header.json",
                "tips/tresr/header.json",
                "tips/ahorra/header.json",
                "tips/hacerhuertos/header.json",
                "tips/haceresquejes/header.json",

        };

        final OptionAdapter adapter = new OptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), headers);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        /*list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                final String path = adapter.getPaths().get(headers[i]);

                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("path", path);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/
    }
}
```

Aquí hay que observar que obtenemos el Spinner por su ID, después en mi caso creo un array que contiene la ruta interna de los archivos **.json** los cuales contiene la información(ruta de la imagen, titulo y descripción), que seria la información que ocuparemos para crear la view personalizada.

no te fijes en la parte comentada, eso era para el original listView, con el Spinner te dará error.

**OptionAdapter.java**

```
public class OptionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final String[] headers;
    private final HashMap<String, String> paths;
    private final Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater inflter;


        public OptionAdapter(Context context, String[] headers) {
            this.headers = headers;
            this.paths = new HashMap<>(headers.length);
            inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        public HashMap<String, String> getPaths() {
            return paths;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return headers.length;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }
    
    
    
        @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"})
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view != null) return view;
    
            view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.option, null);
            final ImageView icon = view.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
            final TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.option_title);
            final TextView preview = view.findViewById(R.id.option_preview);
    
            try {
                String auxPath;
    
                final Gson gson = new Gson();
                final AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
                final Header instance = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(assets.open(headers[i]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Header.class);
    
                title.setText(instance.title);
                preview.setText(instance.preview);
    
                final File parents = new File(headers[i]).getParentFile();
                auxPath = new File(parents, instance.path).toString();
                paths.put(headers[i], auxPath);
    
                auxPath = new File(parents, instance.icon).toString();
                icon.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(assets.open(auxPath), null));
    
            } catch (Throwable ignored) {
            }
    
            return view;
        }
    
        public static class Header {
            String icon, title, preview, path;
        }
    }
```

primero que todo, el constructor, guardamos todo en variables internas y obtenemos el LayoutInflater con el context.

despues como podemos ver, el metodo mas importante que tenemos es **getView(...)**

***¿Qué es exactamente este método?***

bueno mi amigo ese método es el de toda la magia, regresara una "view" vista que es básicamente donde entra lo que queremos, es el meollo de asunto porque esa es la vista que se mirara en el spinner, cada una de la opciones del spinner será obtenida desde este método.

ahora es donde entrar en juego en LayoutInflater..
nos permitirá crear una **view** a partir de un archivo **.xml** ya existente..
luego obtendremos sus views internas y le asignaremos los datos..
también entra en juego los otros datos que nos ayudaran a obtener esos datos.

En mi caso decidí hacerlo de esa modo de pasar la ruta de los archivos **.json** y leerlos, tu puedes hacer algo mas fácil y es pasar un array de un clase personalizada que contenta el titulo, id de la imagen, y la descripción..

pero algo falta, aquí te dejo el archivo **.xml** que ocupe para inflar la vista..
**Option.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/option_background"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/option_icon"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/error" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/option_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/error" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/option_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/error" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

esta demas pero para quedar claros, los archivos **.xml** deben estar en **res/layout**

**Edit**
no entiendo mucho de tu código, yo solo programo en java, arriba esta como lo haría usando java, pero no veo que tu tengas un archivo **.xml** para inflar, la verdad no se que hacer con tu ***Layout Inflater***, puede que sea ese tu problema

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y por la ayuda ^^. no he puesto el archivo XML, cierto es, pero sí lo tengo. Lo inflo através de la técnica ViewBinding, en esta parte del código: 
 val rowView = SpinnerSelectedItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
       val planet = planets[position]
       rowView.txtSpinnerSelectedItemKm.text = planet.order.toString()
       rowView.txtSpinnerSelectedItemName.text = planet.name

De nuevo gracias, voy a revisar tu codigo!